# Laravel using pivot table to generate a raply from database in one request

Tags: laravel

I am using datatables so I need to make a request to my database and get a return in one json.

I have a table of users and a table that is linking the users to them to specify if they have a manager. I m doing this through a pivot table.

```
#User#
id
name

#User_user#
user_id
manager_id
```

I have the following model for the User.php:

```
public function managers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_users' , 'user_id', 'manager_id')->withPivot('manager_type')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_users' , 'manager_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('manager_type')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

In order to generate my data for Datatables, I am using:

```
$userList = $this->user->select('id', 'name','email','is_manager', 'region', 'country', 'domain', 'management_code', 'job_role', 'employee_type');
$data = Datatables::of($userList)->make(true);
```

This gives me the info I need except, I would like to add the manager so that I can use it in datatables. I don't understand how I can configure this in order to get this in 1 reply of the DB using Eloquent.

Comment: I dont understand what is the questions. In order to generate fake data use factories.

Comment: According to your data, I think that a user can have many managers. so how do you want to get a simple manager for a user. Also you have involved `employee_type` in your `users` table which  is a duplicate of your pivot table column `manager_type`. Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: employee_type can be contractor or internal and manager_type is direct or functional... Now for the number of managers, if I can take the first one that is there, it is ok for me